# Did I do sajda sahw correctly?

Tags: salat, sharia, sajda

I was praying Isha and I suddenly forgot how many rakat I prayed but I think I was on the 4th. I genuinely am not sure though. Since I wasn't sure, I did sajda sahw at the end before taslim. Was this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched many places, where I found the answer that **if you forget how many rakats you have done in your prayer, then count the *least* number that you are certain of then, do your sajda sahw**. So in this case, I hope that you are **correct**.

Here are some of the references about your question:

1. [What to do if i forget how many rakat is prayed ? Answered by Dr Zakir Naik](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8BrfWoxFv0)
2. [Doubtful if I prayed 3 or 4 rakahs. Finished 3, made salam & prayed 1 more rakah, is it valid? Assim Al Hakeem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtDCG54UVzM)
3. [What to do when one forgets the number of rakats prayed?](https://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/33802/what-to-do-when-one-forgets-the-number-of-rakats-prayed/)